# ObjectBox example for relations unclear

Tags: objectbox

I am trying to set-up a 1:n relationship but struggling with the [documentation](https://docs.objectbox.io/relations). It says:

```dart
Customer customer = Customer();
customer.orders.add(Order('Order 1'));
customer.orders.add(Order('Order 2'));
// Puts customer and orders:
final customerId = store.box<Customer>().put(customer);
```

but what is `Order('Order 1')` supposed to mean? Has the class `Order` suddenly received another variable called text? So to say, you simply create 2 Order instances to add? Order only contains `int id` in all snippets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That docs page probably had, some time ago, a constructor for `Order` to take some comment text. I've updated the code you're referring to so it doesn't cause more confusion. Basically, what it means, is that you add two individual instances, which results in two objects being put to `Box<Order>` as well as having these two objects both linked as targets in `customer.orders`

Comment: the confusing part was because the documentation uses a similar String with the @Backlink() just some lines above. Ok, everything is clear now :-)